# How to manipulate a website online?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to grab content from another website and display that content on my site. What makes it difficult is that the content I need is generated so I need to provide inputs and click buttons on that other website before I get the content I need. I have found online applications that can do this and I want to know how they are doing it. These sites:

- dexi.io
- import.io

The above sites load the target website into the user's browser window and then use some scripts to type inputs and click buttons. I have attempted to look through their source code through resource monitor but had no luck. How in the world do you:

1. Load another website into the user's browser (iframe maybe?)
2. Type inputs
3. Click buttons

I don't know if there is something out there that can do this. Selenium Webdriver doesn't provide client side functionality. Maybe PhantomJS or some other DOM manipulation tool? I need someplace to start and would appreciate any guidance, thank you!

Comment: There is no way to do that from client side. Think of a site redirecting you to a bank account, suddenly hitting login and then stealing data

Comment: Good point! Maybe server side then? I just want to know how dexi.io or import.io is typing in values and clicking on buttons in the CLIENT browser window.

Comment: It is indeed possible with selenium from server end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into something like [Gouette](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) if you're comfortable writing PHP. It's pretty simple to implement and can click links, enter inputs etc. and the documentation is decent.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a Ajax request you get the HTML text of a page as response. Example:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
x.open('GET', 'URL_HERE', true);
x.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
        if(this.status === 200) {
            alert(this.response);
        }else if(this.status === 0) {
            alert("NOT_ALLOWED: Can't cross this site URL.");
        }else{
            // Request error ; >= 500 || 404 || ...
        }
    }
}
x.send();
```

If the request status is 0 after done you're not allowed to access the other site. It's possible to access some, though.

So you can set the HTML text to a iframe inner (e.g, `iframe.contentWindow.document.write(x.response);`).

## Adding buttons and scripts

It's easy to add some buttons – just add a HTML container as text with a obfuscated ID in the end of the response text, including the HTML of the buttons. You must leave the container featured, with a stronger `z-index`. And the scripts can be added anywhere, but it's better to add them at the end of the response text.

`iframe.contentWindow.document.write("<style>#_my_container_ {z-index: 99999;}</style><div id="_my_container_"><button>Hello</button><script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script></div>");`

Your container can disappear or the events may have problem if sites modifies their page body – but no site do that, only messed sites.

Comment: Nice! Would you happen to know how to click buttons or is that only possible server side?

Comment: @RayLi Add HTML buttons to the response text, then add a external script as HTML `script` to the response text, also. I recommend to add them in a container, like > `<div id="control"><button>x</button><script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script></div>`

Comment: I did a bit more digging and figured out how dexi.io does what it does. Apparently, what I supposed to be manipulating DOM objects clientside was just a frontfacing interface. All the work is actually done on the backend. Dexi.io takes the requested site and then injects their custom code into the page and makes it LOOK LIKE the script is manipulating objects client side. :-P Somewhat like your suggestion.